# com.google.android.gms.location went missing

Tags: android, android-studio, location, android-gps

I'm developing an Android app using GPS location services. I was able to compile and run it yesterday, but today I open the Android Studio and the `LocationListener`, `LocationRequest`, `LocationServices` from the Location package won't import (it says cannot resolve symbol LocationListener).

In fact, I can't see any of the classes of the package when I do <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, for example I can see the classes of the `com.google.android.gms.common.api` package.

Project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "gps.example.com.myapplicationgps"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to simply clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Hi, please provide us the java class where you are tying to access the Location. Also in the new verision of Android Studio, you have in the Create Activity menu a new Map Activity and they do everything for you, try it and copy the gradle and imports necessary.

Comment: i have already tried that, but i did it just because you say so and surprisingly it worked! weird, because i even reimport the project a few times, restart the AS so many times, clean it too. Thank you anyways!

Comment: @Egor i assume that being new in here i can't give you points o recommend you in any way. If i'm wrong please tell me because i want to thank you

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped. I'll add an answer which you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by cleaning and building the project.